# Custom sort of list of dicts Python

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of dicts :

```
ldicts = [{'name': '120-150'}, {'name': '90-120'}, {'name': '150-180'}, {'name': '>= 180'}, {'name': '<90'}, {'name': 'total'}]
```

I'd like to sort it by value ascending so that the output would be like this :

```
 sortedldicts = [{'name': 'total'}, {'name': '<90'}, {'name': '90-120'},{'name': '120-150'}, {'name': '150-180'}, {'name': '>= 180'}]
```

The normal sort doesn't do the trick :

```
from operator import itemgetter
sortedldicts = sorted(ldicts , key=itemgetter('name'), reverse=True)
```

So i'm assuming I should do a custom sort maybe? Any hints or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why exactly sorted doesn't work?

Comment: this is the output : `[{'name': 'total'}, {'name': '>= 180'}, {'name': '<90'}, {'name': '90-120'}, {'name': '150-180'}, {'name': '120-150'}]`

Comment: I think you can just use `sortedldicts = sorted(ldicts, reverse=True)`, the output is correct.

Comment: It gives me the same output in my previous comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Extract digits using `re.findall`:

```
>>> ldicts = [{'name': '120-150'}, {'name': '90-120'}, {'name': '150-180'}, {'name': '>= 180'}, {'name': '<90'}, {'name': 'total'}]
>>>
>>> import re
>>> sorted(ldicts, key=lambda d: map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', d['name'])))
[{'name': 'total'}, {'name': '<90'}, {'name': '90-120'}, {'name': '120-150'}, {'name': '150-180'}, {'name': '>= 180'}]
```

- Replace `map(int, ...)` with `list(map(int, ...))` if you use Python 3.x.

Comment: How does it work? `key` returns a list in this case, right? So, the lists are compared?

Comment: @thefourtheye, key function returns a list of int. `[[120,150], [90,120], [150,180], [180], [90], []]`. And the items are used as comparison keys.

Comment: what kind of magic is this? I tried it with : `ldicts= [{'name': '120-150'}, {'name': '90-120'}, {'name': '150-180'}, {'name': 'greater than or equal to 180'}, {'name': 'below 90'}, {'name': 'total'}]` and it works the same. Anyway thank you so much.

Comment: @user1734229, What do you mean *works the same*? Does this not work for you?

Comment: @falsetru Yup. But how? What would be the result if `[120,150]` is compared against `[90,120]`? On what basis, the comparison will be done?

Comment: @thefourtheye, The first items of the lists are compared first. If they are same, next items are compared, .... If the one is bigger than the other, that is the result of the comparison. So `[120,150] > [90,120]`.

Comment: @falsetru +1 Seriously? This is awesome :)

Comment: Reference [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types). Nice answer!

Comment: @thefourtheye, See [*Comparing sequences and other types* - Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types).